# UIAlertView -show causing a memory leak

Tags: iphone, uialertview, retain, memory-leaks

I'm relatively new to iPhone Development, so this may be my fault, but it goes against what I've seen. :)

I think that I'm creating a UIAlertView that lives just in this vaccuum of the 'if' statement.

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(!data)
{
    // Add an alert
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:@"Unable to contact server"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    NSLog(@"retain count before show: %i", alert.retainCount);
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"retain count before release: %i", alert.retainCount);
    [alert release];
    NSLog(@"retain count after release: %i", alert.retainCount);
    return nil;
}
```

However, the console logs baffle me.

```
retain count before show: 1
retain count before release: 6
retain count after release: 5
```

I've tried also adding:

```
alert = nil;
```

after the release.  That makes the retain count 0, but I still show a leak.  And if it helps, the leak's Responsible Frame is UIKeyboardInputManagerClassForInputMode.  I'm also using OS 4 Beta 3.

So anyone have any ideas how a local UIAlertView's retain count would increment itself by 5 when calling -show?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing -- with the Release version of iOS 4.1.  The Release doesn't seem to matter, and I tried Autorelease instead -- same thing.  This must be a bug in the OS, right?

Comment: I see the same thing today under iOS 4.1, and thank you for this question.

Comment: but how is it possible to solve this problem?
i'm in the same situation. after allocation the retainccount is 1;
after showing alertView the retaincount is 6
after releasing it retaincount stays 5 -> and a memory leak occurs

Comment: mock p: There is no problem at all. It is just, that with release you remove YOUR retain. And after all the other windows and controllers remove their retain the alertView object will be killed. If you won't release it, the retain count will remain at 1 after all the others released the object and you would have a leak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes some sense if you realize that [alert show] doesn't immediately put the alert up on screen.  I think what happens is that the [alert show] adds the alert to some queue somewhere in the system which retains it.  *It won't actually be shown until you return from this function and get back to the event loop.*   When it eventually gets dismissed those retain counts will get decremented and it will be released then.

If you were to log messages from UIAlertView's delegate routines, such as didPresentAlertView, I'll bet that doesn't happen until after your function ends, after you've "released" the alert.  Release doesn't always mean deallocate, it is just relinquishing ownership.  It only causes a dealloc if there are no owners left.

Answer (score 3):

I highly doubt this is a memory leak. The alert view is just getting shown: it is getting added to the window, etc: which all retain what they own. I bet you that if you check once it has been closed, it won't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that this is related to the beta sdk. There are many errors/bugs in the betas. I would suggest checking it with the 3.1.3 or 3.2 sdk.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but I was just wondering if I was crazy or if this was intended behavior for some odd reason. Thanks!